# Convert from hex string to unicode

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, encode, decode

How can i convert the `'dead'` string to an unicode string `u'\xde\xad'`?

Doing this:

```
from binascii import unhexlify
out = ''.join(x for x in [unhexlify('de'), unhexlify('ad')])
```

creates a `<type 'str'>` string `'\xde\xad'`

Trying to use the Unicode.join() like this:

```
from binascii import unhexlify
out = ''.join(x for x in [u'', unhexlify('de'), unhexlify('ad')])
```

results in an error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xde in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unicode is designed to be compatible with Latin-1, you can use that and simply decode the bytestring:

```
In [2]: unhexlify('dead').decode('latin1')
Out[2]: u'\xde\xad'
```

Answer (score 1):

See [this Python unicode how-to](http://www.amk.ca/python/howto/unicode), and use something akin to:

```
unicode('\x80abc', errors='replace')
```

or

```
unicode('\x80abc', errors='ignore')
```